# Form data not retained after cancel action - Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm using Struts1.3 where for a requirement I'm using two jsp. In first jsp I'm asking for required data and based on that data, the second jsp is populated. The problem is when I click on Cancel button is second jsp, which refers to a method in my Action class forwarding to first jsp, the previous data in first jsp is getting erased, but while debugging, the Form object has all the required values. Can somebody please help me to restore those values to jsp.

Comment: `I'm using Struts1.3` Sorry, I've stop reading there. However, don't tag it Struts2 if it's not Struts2.

Comment: sorry @ Andrea Ligios, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to store your form in session while it has all the data in servlet action. In jsp, load the values from session. On a following request u should remove this object from session and get the data from your form in the request.

Edit: Actually ,I believe , as I don't see any code here, you do a full new load of the form when invoking the cancel action, which is not a solution in this case. ;)